# Delete a cookie across all domain using Javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a cookie  in two domain([www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com) and .www.abc.com) . I want to delete the cookie across all domains. Otherwise, I need a logic to read cookie specific to a domain.

I tried the below code to delete the cookies from all domains, it doesnt work.

document.cookie = 'cookieName=; path=/; domain=*;expires=' + new Date(0).toUTCString();

Comment: Cookies can be set with the [`HttpOnly` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#httponly). Those cannot be changed/deleted from JavaScript.

Comment: I am creating cookies in JS using this code  document.cookie = "cname=cvalue;path=/;domain=.abc.com"; But I am seeing two cookies in my browser with different domain as mentioned above. Why?

Comment: I can't reproduce that. When I run that line of code, it only adds a single cookie for the `.abc.com` domain. Maybe you already set it for a different domain earlier?

Comment: `domain=*` - I don't think trying to use a "wildcard" like this, is valid in the first place. Plus, quote MDN, _"Contrary to earlier specifications, leading dots in domain names are ignored, but browsers may decline to set the cookie containing such dots. If a domain is specified, subdomains are always included."_